# Does Hanzee kill the boys off screen?

Tags: character, fargo-tv

In the TV show *Fargo* season 2, Hanzee is seen pulling his knife out and walking towards two boy bullies.

The scene can be seen here:
[Starting from 2:11](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n3qLhUg70C8)

Does it suggest Hanzee actually kill those bullies off screen?

- I will say it is a bit excessive even for Hanzee to kill off strangers, especially children.

Comment: Well, he seems pretty determined, and as he says in the dialogue with "The Book", he wants to start an empire on his own. It would be a good way to show to Mr. Numbers and Mr. Wrench how serious he is and recruiting them.